# <a> link breaks SVG transition

Tags: svg, css-transitions

I am actually facing a strange issue with SVG and CSS3 transition property.

I have a simple SVG :

```
<svg version="1.1" class="world" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 200">
<g id="US East" class="interesting">
    <polyline points="(...)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

With this Sass/Compass style:

```
.world {
  display: block;
  width:250px;
  height: 200px; 
}

.world .interesting {
  fill: #759a41;
  @include transition-property(fill);
  @include transition-duration(0.3s);
}

.world .interesting:hover {
    fill: #aee265;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It is working like a charm. Until I had a SVG link `<a xlink:href="#">(...)</a>`. It suddenly breaks the transition animation, and I can't figure it out why.

In action : [a link mess it up! (CodePen)](http://cdpn.io/JcBtI)

This guy seems to have a solution, but I can't find the difference with mine: http://f.cl.ly/items/3r2J2B0j470U0I3t2K3p/logo.svg

Any idea?

EDIT: It is Chrome issue on some specific url. Works well in Safari.

Comment: Which browsers is it messing up?  I can hover over both islands on http://codepen.io/kimchouard/full/JcBtI and some transition occurs.  BTW, I'm in Chrome 28.0.1500.72 (which is probably an old version because this machine hasn't been turned on in a while).

Comment: In the solution link you provided, it behaves very differently -- its color remains altered until you mouse out of the window itself, not out of just the image.  Running chrome Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Comment: I'm with Chrome 28.0.1500.71, and you are right, it is working. Finally, it is even weird than that. It is the href itself that make the animation break... Take a look back to the link http://codepen.io/kimchouard/pen/JcBtI o.O

Comment: @KimC. Hey! Having the same issue, but it also happens in Safari and Firefox. Did you find any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I have a technical explanation for what's happening here, but after having the same exact problem, doing some extensive researching, and playing with the codepens referenced above, it looks like there is a difference between using "http://" and "https://" in your xlink:href attribute.

This will allow the CSS3 transition to work perfectly:

xlink:href="https://www.w3.org"

This will cause the transition to break:

xlink:href="http://www.w3.org"

Both links will take you to the same website. Very strange, but it worked for me.